# "Announcer" badge without having posted a link?

Tags: bug, badges

You have earned the "Announcer" badge (Share a link to a post later visited by 25 unique IP addresses) for [Endpoint for Cloud Function returns 403 Forbidden](https://serverfault.com/a/1010147/607547).

[image]

It opens at the answer, with my comment below it. But I did not put a link in the comment, nor did I edit a link into the answer.

Why do I get the badge? Could it be a bug?

Comment: Hi, I asked in the TL, to see if a know bug exist, I will let you know, maybe the question might be better suited for MSE too, but I will let you know when I will have some feedback

Comment: @yagmoth555 Right, it will not just be a bug of this SE only. If you will, you can move it to MSE, as you like. My guess: 25 quite new SE users clicked on my username since it it so long, checking whether there could be the link to the other error I write about right before my username. Since it starts with question42. Should not be counted either, though.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I flagged it to be moved to Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: I tried to move but sadly as you are blocked from asking there the move got rejected. Lets wait to see if someone can answer here I would guess

Comment: @yagmoth555 Yes I had just got the right to ask after roughly half a year of ban time. Then I got downvoted heavily for the first new question I had. And that has led to a new ban again. That ban algorithm can get better.